# Multiple ingress objects one service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to create multiple ingress objects with similar rules referencing the same backend service on the same port?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: green.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: red-svc
          servicePort: 80

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: pink.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: red-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: btw, if you're just creating separate ingress to route to same service with separate hostnames. How about adding another rule in the same ingress with a different host?

Comment: Good shout. How would you handle this though if each host requires a TLS certificate?

Comment: if you look in the ingress examples, you would see that each host block has its own tls section. https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation of the ingress controller you are using. For nginx below rules apply while building the [nginx model](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#building-the-nginx-model)

1. If the same path for the same host is defined in more than one Ingress, the oldest rule wins.
2. f multiple Ingresses define different paths for the same host, the ingress controller will merge the definitions

Since you have different host none of the above apply and it should fine i.e both
`green.com` and `pink.com` should route traffic to the same backend `red-svc` on port `80`